# Why spyder can't import tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

I have installed tensorflow with anaconda in Windows, but I can't import tensorflow in spyder IDE?

Answer (score 0):

The reason Spyder is unable to import Tensorflow is that Anaconda does not store the tensorflow package in the same environment.

One solution is to create a new separate environment in Anaconda dedicated to TensorFlow and containing Python with its own Spyder and then install tensorflow into that environment