# Tensorflow import error: No module named 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

I installed TensorFlow on my Windows Python 3.5 Anaconda environment
The validation was successful (with a warning)

```
(tensorflow) C:\>python
```

Python 3.5.3 |Intel Corporation| (default, Apr 27 2017, 17:03:30) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Intel(R) Distribution for Python is brought to you by Intel Corporation.
Please check out: https://software.intel.com/en-us/python-distribution

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
```

2017-10-04 11:06:13.569696: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.

```
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
```

b'Hello, TensorFlow!'

However, when I attempt to import it into my python code

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib
import tensorflow as tf
```

I get this error

> **ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'**

This is the location of the tensorflow package on my C drive

```
C:\Users\myname\Anaconda2\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow
```

When I go to Anaconda Navigator, it seems I have to choose either root, Python35, or Tensorflow. It looks like the Tensorflow environment includes Python35.

Anaconda Navigator launcher had to be reinstalled recently, possibly due to the Tensorflow installation. Maybe if there were another way to set the environment to Tensorflow within Anaconda /Spyder IDE other than the Navigator it might help

Method of installing tensorflow

```
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5; 
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

I did try:
uninstalling and reinstalling protobuf, as suggesed by some blogs

I see another SO user asked [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619665/why-spyder-cant-import-tensorflow) in March, received no reply

Comment: Please show us how you run your script that produces the import error. It seems like you aren't using your conda environment for that.

Comment: @Dietmar. I am in Spyder 3.5 console.How can I best show my environment

Comment: I am not familiar with Spyder. But it seems it currently does not use your conda environment with tensorflow.
Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34237461/1534243

Comment: @Dietmar. Thanks for the response. Anaconda Spyder works very well in most respects. Just this particular import is problematic

Comment: this solution works for me, thanks for providing solution

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The reason Python 3.5 environment is unable to import Tensorflow is that Anaconda does not store the tensorflow package in the same environment.

One solution is to create a new separate environment in Anaconda dedicated to TensorFlow with its own Spyder

```
conda create -n newenvt anaconda python=3.5
activate newenvt
```

and then install tensorflow into *newenvt*

I found [this primer](http://lifeofajenni.com/2017/02/22/python-2x-and-3x-in-spyder/) helpful

Comment: how to install tensorflow into the newenvt? just type "brew install tensorflow" again?? I am very new to this AI land, please help, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

In Windows 64, if you did this sequence correctly:

Anaconda prompt:

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

Be sure you still are in tensorflow environment. The best way to make Spyder recognize your tensorflow environment is to do this:

```
conda install spyder
```

This will install a new instance of Spyder inside Tensorflow environment. Then you must install scipy, matplotlib, pandas, sklearn and other libraries. Also works for OpenCV.

Always prefer to install these libraries with "conda install" instead of "pip".

Answer (score 15):

The reason why Python base environment is unable to import Tensorflow is that Anaconda does not store the tensorflow package in the base environment.

create a new separate environment in **Anaconda** dedicated to TensorFlow as follows:

```
conda create -n newenvt anaconda python=python_version
```

replace python_version by your python version

activate the new environment as follows:

```
activate newenvt
```

Then install tensorflow into the new environment (newenvt) as follows:

```
conda install tensorflow
```

Now you can check it by issuing the following python code and it will work fine.

```
import tensorflow
```

Answer (score 5):

deleting tensorflow from cDrive/users/envs/tensorflow and after that

```
conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6
 activate tensorflow
 pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow
```

now its working for newer versions of python thank you

Comment: I hope this issue is soled now for everyone

Answer (score 3):

I think your tensorflow is not installed for local environment.The best way of installing tensorflow is to create virtualenv as describe in the tensorflow installation guide
[Tensorflow Installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingVirtualenv)
.After installing you can activate the invironment and can run anypython script under that environment.

Answer (score 2):

In Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda 3),
Type: `conda install tensorflow` command

This fix my issue in my Anaconda with Python 3.8.

Reference: https://panjeh.medium.com/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tensorflow-in-jupeter-1425afe23bd7

Comment: thanks Samsul Islam for editing my answer.

Answer (score 2):

for Python3 :

1. `!pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow`
2. `!pip show tensorflow`
3. `import tensorflow as tf`

Answer (score 1):

I had same issues on Windows 64-bit processor but manage to solve them.
Check if your Python is for 32- or 64-bit installation.
If it is for 32-bit, then you should download the executable installer (for e.g. you can choose latest Python version - for me is 3.7.3)
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-373/ -> Scroll to the bottom in Files section and select “Windows x86-64 executable installer”. Download and install it.

The tensorflow installation steps check here : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip .
I hope this helps somehow ...

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the above solve my issue, I will post my solution

> WARNING: if you just installed TensorFlow using conda, you have to restart your command prompt!

Solution: restart terminal **ENTIRELY** and restart conda environment

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio in left panel is Python  "interactive Select karnel"

> Pyton 3.7.x 
>     anaconda3/python.exe ('base':conda)
>    I'm this fixing

Answer (score 1):

I deleted all the folders and files in C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs and then I wrote `conda install tensorflow` in Anaconda Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

for python 3.8 version
go for anaconda navigator 
then go for environments --> then go for base(root)----> not installed from drop box--->then search for tensorflow then install it then run the program.......hope it may helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try worked for me

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Comment: I think it is better to elaborate on your choice of this typical `.whl` file. How could it fix the import error? What's the difference from a "normal" installation (`pip install tensorflow`)

Answer (score 0):

Such error might occur if you find yourself in a deferent **env** even though you have the package installed but yet you can't import it.

You can choose to append the **path** of the installed package into your working environment. If you tried other approaches and yet did not succeed.

Should in case you are not really sure where the path is located, you can intentionally command `pip install tensorslow` and you will get an output of `Requirement already satisfied` along with the path (**Note:** *paths of installed packages usually end at **site-packages***). Copy the path and get back to your working environment and do the below operations:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/past/the/copied/path/here")
import tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

### ***WHAT YOU DID RIGHT:***

- You have created a new environment called 'tensorflow'
- You installed tensorflow in your environment

### ***WHAT WENT WRONG:***

- If you are using jupyter-notebook:

> It is the installation from the base environment which access the base packages not your tensorflow packages

- If you are using python file:

> The local python installation packages are being used.

## ***SOLUTIONS***

### **Solution for the 1st problem :**

```
conda activate yourenvironment
pip install notebook
jupyter-notebook
```

- Now run your code on the jupyter-notebook which is found in yourenvironment.
- **Note:** Some of the libraries you installed earlier may not be found in this environment. Install them again.

### **Solution for the 2nd problem:**

- On your computer (PC) search and open "Edit **the** system environment variables", then "Environment Variables..." then "Path".
- Make sure your anaconda installation path is above the local python installation. Click Ok [for each 3 windows opened]
  [Your path should look like as in the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAJiT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I installed jupyterlab version 3.2.1 and my error solved

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jupyter notebook then,
Go to jupyter->home page->new->terminal
Run : pip install tensorflow
This worked for me!