# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_slim' despite installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, ubuntu, bioinformatics

I'd like to run `call_variants.py` from `deepvariant`. I was struggling for hours ans hours installing cuda, tensorflow etc... Unfortunately I ran into a problem and I don't know what to do. Let's start from the beginning:

```
conda create --name tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
python --version
Python 3.7.9
python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
2.3.0
```

Now I tried to run the command:

```
python ${h_dir}/deepvariant/binaries/DeepVariant/1.0.0/DeepVariant-1.0.0/call_variants.zip \
--outfile ${test_dir}/test.gz \
--examples ${ex_dir}/ex_test.gz --checkpoint $model
```

I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/Bazel.runfiles_i55m5mpq/runfiles/com_google_deepvariant/deepvariant/call_variants.py", line 57, in <module>
    from deepvariant import modeling
  File "/tmp/Bazel.runfiles_i55m5mpq/runfiles/com_google_deepvariant/deepvariant/modeling.py", line 51, in <module>
    import tf_slim
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_slim'
```

So of course I decided to install it:

```
pip install tf_slim
Collecting tf_slim
  Using cached tf_slim-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (352 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: absl-py>=0.2.2 in ./anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from tf_slim) (0.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from absl-py>=0.2.2->tf_slim) (1.15.0)
Installing collected packages: tf-slim
Successfully installed tf-slim-1.1.0
```

However:

```
python3 -c 'import tf_slim as slim; print(slim.__version__)'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'tf_slim' has no attribute '__version__'
```

An of course `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_slim'` after running the command. So maybe install with conda?

```
conda install -c conda-forge tf-slim
```

But it didn't help at all... I have no clue what to do next, looking forward to any ideas!

Edit:
When I run something like this:

```
try:
    import tf_slim as slim
    print("module 'tf_slim' is installed")
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    print("module 'tf_slim' is not installed")

python test.py
module 'tf_slim' is installed
```

But after command, still `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_slim'`

¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got it. As you may see I used conda to create enviroment for tensorflow. As I read, this procedure is recommended, otherwise you may encounter something like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'` which has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568913/tensorflow-import-error-no-module-named-tensorflow). So what I did?
I deactivated and removed any conda enviroment and I decided to run my command without it, just in terminal. First, however I run the command with `python3` then I occured same error that's `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_slim'` and I installed it with `pip3 install tf_slim` and it worked! Next I run deepvariant script postprocess_variants.py and I had the same problem with `altair` module but I did the same and the both commands worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall `tf_slim` and then again install the `tf_slim` package, it will work.