# How to install tensorflow in win 10

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

The tensorflow is installed by using "conda install tensorflow". by importing tensorflow with "import tensorflow" in spyder in same environment which tensorflow was installed, it give an error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'".

Comment: Are you able to import tensorflow outside of spyder in the conda environment? Like in a test python script?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. it fixed. The solution is mentioned in answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow import error: No module named 'tensorflow'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568913/tensorflow-import-error-no-module-named-tensorflow)

Answer (score 1):

For every one who is faced with this problem i suggest to check if they have already installed spyder in desired environment with "conda install spyder". I installed it and the problem fixed