# ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'tensorflow.python' when trying to import tensorflow module

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, tensorflow2.0

I am working on a project where I have to use TensorFlow and Keras modules on my Windows10 machine.
I first created my virtual env using anaconda prompt

```
$ conda create -n tensor-env
$ conda activate tensor-env
```

After this, I have installed some python libraries that I need to use.

When I do `$conda list` I can see that TensorFlow is installed ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cnXr.png)).

But after this and when I try to use it on my .py files I get an error message saying that it can't find the module ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsIeA.png)).

Am I missing something here? I've tried many tutorials so far and I can't see how to fix this problem, am I missing CPU TensorFlow installation or something?

Thank you everyone for reading it :)

Comment: May you please show the output of `conda show tensorflow`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46568913/

Comment: I cant do that comand, it says: No command 'conda show'. But when i do ` conda list` i can see tensorflow=2.3.0
But i have solved this issue now, i belive the problem was that i was using Python=3.9 and isnt supported for tensorflow, so i downgraded to Python=3.8 and apparently i have no import errors once again.
But now i am facing a new error in this line of code `loss = keras.losses.SparseCategorialCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` saying that module 'tensorflow.keras.losses' has no attribute 'SparseCategoricalCrossentropy'. Any ideia how to solve it? i already had this error weeks ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating virtual environment , you again need to install tensorflow and keras into that environment to run your program.

You can run below commands in anaconda prompt.

```
conda create -n tensor-env

conda activate tensor-env

conda install tensorflow

conda install keras
```

Now select this environment in anaconda navigator and open the jupyter notebook in same environment to run the program.
Please let me know if this resolve your program error.

Comment: Thank you very much, it sure did solve my problem! I was having some issue with anaconda, that when i restarted my laptop all my installed modules were gone from the env. But its all fine now, i mannaged to solve it, thank you very much for your time and effort to reply.

Comment: Great that I could help you, Please mark if this answer was useful. Thanks!