# streamlit run :ImportError: cannot import name 'tf2' from 'tensorflow.python' (unknown location)

Tags: tensorflow, web-applications, streamlit

this my code
[image]
this result
[image]

`python = 3.10.0`

`keras = 2.6.0`

`tensorfow = 2.3.0`

`streamlit = 1.11.0`

i want to run streamlit app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can not import tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73621205/19290081)

Comment: Please don't provide code for your problem as code block in text format and not as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

your tensorflow is to old or keras to new.
maybe try:

```
pip uninstall keras
pip install keras==2.2.1
```

to install an older keras version